# mysql fallback WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, where-clause

suppose I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field2 = '2019@162440' OR field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%';
```

In this case, it will try to execute the matching of BOTH `field2 = '2019@162440'`and `field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%'` conditions (ie, it will search for rows matching those conditions hence it takes some more computation power to try to find rows matching both condition even if it already found a row matching `field2 = '2019@162440'`)

Is there a way to instruct mysql by reforming the query to ONLY try to execute `field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%'` if the condition `field2 = '2019@162440'` does not match anything so that the query becomes more efficient

IE. I essentially want mysql to only try to find rows matching `field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%'` only if no rows match `field2 = '2019@162440'`. If a  row that matches `field2 = '2019@162440'` is found, do NOT try to match `field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%'`

Also, no subqueries

Comment: Does this work: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field2 = '2019@162440' OR (field2 != '2019@162440' AND field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%');`

Comment: it would return the same

Comment: @AdrianBR Yeah, but would that keep mysql from doing both checks? I'm asking here, I have no idea.

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad Nope it will still try to search for field2 LIKE etc

Comment: Using leading wildcards prevents indexes from being used properly, do you have to start with %%? This will definitely speed up your query if it is slow, unfortunately I don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: MySQL's lack of a WITH statement is going to make this difficult... thinking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can do is use the FOUND_ROWS() function along with a UNION:

```
SELECT *  
FROM t  
WHERE field2 = '2019@162440'

UNION ALL

SELECT *  
FROM t   
WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0 
      AND field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/784c8/67)

Comment: nope an explain would reveal that it's scanning a whole bunch of rows during the UNION select

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by stating that I am not an expert in MySQL. It is not nearly as optimized as some other DBMSes, so the following query might not actually reduce your execution time. But it's worth a shot...

If `field2` is indexed, this might be a really fast solution:

```
-- Get results where field2 = '2019@162440'
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   field2 = '2019@162440'
-- Append...
UNION
-- Get results where field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%' but only
-- if there are no rows where field2 = '2019@162440'
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT  *
            FROM    table
            WHERE   field2 = '2019@162440'
        )
    AND field2 LIKE '%%2019@%%'
```

You are going to run your fastest query and select all results. Then, append the second, slower query which contains an EXISTS. The EXISTS clause will return true if the subquery contains any rows, which should short-circuit the entire second query and prevent it from runnning (thus appending 0 rows). If the first query returns 0 rows, however, then the second query will kick in and run the slower `LIKE` comparisons.